# Multiple keyboard presses

Tags: java, key

Does Java support multi key press and how to implement that? This solution is not working at all:

```
if (key == KeyEvent.VK_LEFT) {
    if(key==KeyEvent.VK_S){

        dx = -3;
                          }
    }
```

Comment: What in the world are you trying to do? `VK_LEFT` != `VK_S`, how could  key be equal to both of them? Do you want `dx = -3` to execute when both of the keys are pressed simultaneously? Or when either one is pressed?

Comment: Sorry ! this was just an exemple and yes i want to execute dx=-3 when the two Buttons are pressed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no such built-in feature so you will have to deal with it yourself. For example make a collection of the last `KEY_PRESSED` `KeyEvent`s and check that for your combinations. When a key is released, i.e. `KEY_RELEASED`, you can remove it from the collection.

If you're looking for shift, ctrl, alt or alt gr there is a simpler solution - the KeyEvent has the methods `isShiftDown()`, `isControlDown()`, `isAltDown()` and `isAltGraphDown()` that tells you if these were down on the event.